# How rotate label in google chart?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I added: `hAxis: { title: 'hTitle', direction: -1, slantedText: true, slantedTextAngle: 45 }` into options.

I want to rotate the label by a 45 degree angle, but it doesn't work.

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
<script>
  google.charts.load('current', {
    callback: drawBasic,
    packages: ['bar']
  });

  function drawBasic() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Example', 'Example', ],
      ["a", 12],
      ["b", 10],
      ["c", 15],
      ["d", 13],
      ["e", 54],
      ["f", 20],
      ["g", 30]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'title',
      subtitle: "subtitle",
      vAxis: {
        title: 'vTitle',
      },
      hAxis: {
        title: 'hTitle',
        direction: -1,
        slantedText: true,
        slantedTextAngle: 45
      },
      colors: ['#e91e63']
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document
      .getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

  }
</script>
```

[image: My result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bar chart doesn't support slantedText, You need to switch to ColumnChart instead if you want to use slantedText you can verify by checking the supported properties in the docs for both [BarChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart) and [ColumnChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart)

Also, The supported slantedTextAngle values are -90 and 90

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
<script>
  

 google.charts.load('current', {
    callback: drawBasic,
    packages: ['corechart']
  });
 function drawBasic() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Example', 'Example', ],
      ["a", 12],
      ["b", 10],
      ["c", 15],
      ["d", 13],
      ["e", 54],
      ["f", 20],
      ["g", 30]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'title',
      subtitle: "subtitle",
      vAxis: {
        title: 'vTitle',
      },
      hAxis: {
        title: 'hTitle',
        direction: -1,
        slantedText: true,
      },
      colors: ['#e91e63']
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization
    .ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
 }
</script>
```